# OpenCV stitcher.stitch Errors

Tags: c++, objective-c, opencv, ios7.1, xcode5.1

I am running OpenCV 2.4.3 on Mac OS X 10.8.5 and IOs device Iphone5 IOs is IOs7.1 I am trying to use the cv::Mat stitch (vector& images) to get panorama image.

This is the code I am using to do the detection and paint a bounding box.

```
cv::Mat stitch (vector<Mat>& images){
    imgs = images;
    Mat pano;
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(try_use_gpu);
    stitcher.setRegistrationResol(1); /// 0.6
    stitcher.setSeamEstimationResol(1);   /// 0.1
    stitcher.setCompositingResol(1);   //1
    stitcher.setPanoConfidenceThresh(1);   //1
    stitcher.setWaveCorrection(true);
    stitcher.setWaveCorrectKind(detail::WAVE_CORRECT_HORIZ);
    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano);
    Stitcher::Status status1= stitcher.estimateTransform(imgs);
    if (status != Stitcher::OK)
    {
         cout << "Can't stitch images, error code = " << int(status)<<"Estimate Transform :"<<int(status1) << endl;
    }
    return pano;
}
```

However, when the execution reaches the line.

```
    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano);
```

I get the an error and the whole application crashes

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dsize.area() || (inv_scale_x > 0 && inv_scale_y > 0))in resize, file /Volumes/minijHome/Documents/xcode_mini/hillegass/advancedIOS/postCourse/openCV/clean-downloads/openCVgitClone/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp, line 1726 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Volumes/minijHome/Documents/xcode_mini/hillegass/advancedIOS/postCourse/openCV/clean-downloads/openCVgitClone/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:1726: error: (-215) dsize.area() || (inv_scale_x > 0 && inv_scale_y > 0) in function resize
```

What is going wrong? I cannot seem to get any new information from the gdb or lldb outputs. I am compiling with the code with a Xcode5.1 and IOs7.1 build, Please suggest to me. what is going wrong..

Thank you

Comment: Does it work if you use just the

    cv::Mat stitch (vector<Mat>& images){
        Mat pano;
        Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(try_use_gpu);
        Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(images, pano);
        return pano;
    }

?

Comment: yes.. it's work fine on xcode5 and IOs7

Comment: So, I'm assuming you want every step of the algorithm to work on the original resolution. Is that so? If yes, could you try using a negative value when setting the parameters? Like, stitcher.setRegistrationResol(-1); stitcher.setSeamEstimationResol(-1); stitcher.setCompositingResol(-1);

Comment: this error does not relate to resolution of image.i have checked. i think this error related to standard architecture64. my app run smoothly on iphone5 and app crash on Iphone5s and IOs is IOs7.1 Please   suggest to me solution of this error..

Comment: Unfortunately, in that case I can't suggest anything useful. My guess would be that something is wrong with binary compatibility of the library. So, I would try to build it from source for armv7s, but it will not necessarily help. And also the process is not really straightforward if you haven't done it before.